# Efficient method of inserting jQuery elements within template literals

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, template-literals

Dabbling in jQuery, there's an awkward situation I find myself running into often. Say I want to construct a big chunk of HTML, with a jQuery-wrapped element somewhere in the middle. I want to be able to use a template literal to do the HTML, and then efficiently drop the jQuery-wrapped element in, to avoid writing loads of JavaScript code to build each element individually in the tree.

For example, say I wanted to insert a button at the position described:

```
const $btn = $(`<button>Click Me</button>`).click(() => { /* complex handler... */ });
const $ele = $(`<div><h1>Some content</h1><p>Press this button: [button should go here]</p></div>`);
```

I could laboriously create the outer `div`, the `p`, append the `p` to the `div`, and append the `button` to the `p`. This feels like a lot of clunky boilerplate.

I could, instead, add the `button` directly to the template literal:

```
<div><h1>Some content</h1><p>Press this button: <button>Click Me</button></p></div>
```

And then `find()` it and bind handlers that way--this seems a little better, but I'm still going to have to give my `button` a unique `id` or `class` in order to be able to `find` it, depending on the context. It also doesn't "chain" well, as, for example above, tacking a `find()` to the end of my `const $ele = ..` statement will result in `$ele` storing the `button`, and not the `div`. This is undesirable more often than not.

So, is there a better solution?

Comment: Instead of constructing a string of HTML, make a jQuery object of DOM nodes.

Comment: can't be done with string literals because a jQuery object is not a string. Somehow you need to append it. into the element or find it. The best solution really depends on what you are doing.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this that will work in all situations. Handle it case by case. Either strictly deal with strings, or you'll have to use dom manipulation methods.

Comment: Consider using a JavaScript-based template engine.  Whatever you do, don't just concatenate arbitrary text data into the context of HTML, or you risk creating invalid HTML and security problems.

Comment: Did I just read *efficient* and *jQuery*  in the same sentence? jQuery is about convenience, not efficiency in the sense of performance.

Comment: Looking at this question again, I think the real issue you're poking at is the event handler?  If so, just add an appropriate attribute to your button and use a selector later on.  I use something like `data-action="someActionName"`, and then when I add click handlers, I just look for `[data-action="someActionName"]`.

Comment: What you want sounds like a perfect usecase for templates and slots.

Comment: Woah. That's almost exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: And, yes, I suppose I meant "efficient" from a coding/maintaining standpoint, the execution performance can... never _really_ take a backseat, but you get the idea.

Comment: @epascarello "*can't be done*" did challenge me - see my answer :-)

Comment: Man that is horrible @Bergi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have some fun with tagged template literals:

```js
const $btn = jQuery(`<button>Click Me</button>`).click(e => alert("complex handler…"));
const $ele = $`<div><h1>Some content</h1><p>Press this button: ${$btn}</p></div>`;
//           ^^                                                ^^^^^^^          ^
jQuery("body").append($ele);

function $(parts, ...args) {
  const uid = Math.round(Math.random()*0xFFFF).toString(16).padStart(4, "0");
  const res = jQuery(parts.reduce((html, p, i) => {
    return html + "<slot name=x-replace-"+uid+"></slot>" + p;
  }));
  res.find("slot[name=x-replace-"+uid+"]").replaceWith(i => args[i]);
  return res;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `find()` it in string and then add properties to it, you can `find()` the `p` element and append the button to it. This way an `id` is not required like in the other case as you mentioned:

```js
const $btn = $("<button>Click Me</button>").click(() => { /* complex handler... */ });
const $ele = $("<div><h1>Some content</h1><p>Press this button: </p></div>");
$ele.find("p").append($btn)

//This line is only for testing:
$ele.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sure, in this simple example--but this approach doesn't "scale" well, and is difficult to maintain. What if, later, I add another `p` to the template string, before the target?

Comment: Well, give us the required HTML so we can help you. There is no answer that will work in all situations. We cannot solve the world's problems, we only need to solve our problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is a hot topic, so, combining some of the ideas here, is this stupid?:

```
$.fn.extend({
    swapIn: function (toSwap) {
        Object.entries(toSwap)
            .forEach(([k, $v]) => this.find(`[data-swap="${k}"]`).replaceWith($v));
        return this;
    }
});

const $btn1 = $(`<button>Click Me</button>`).click(() => { /* complex handler... */ });
const $btn2 = $(`<button>Don't Click Me</button>`).click(() => { /* complex handler... */ });
const $ele = $(`<div><h1>Some content</h1><p>Press this button: <div data-swap="$btn1"/> but not this button: <div data-swap="$btn2"/></p></div>`)
    .swapIn({$btn1, $btn2});

console.log($ele[0].innerHTML); // the desired resut, while keeping the jQuery objects handy for further manipulation
```

It satisfies the requirements of:

- Easy to use/minimal boilterplate
- Easy-ish to read (in my opinion)--can be read top-to-bottom
- Chain friendly
- Maintains jQuery objects
- Allows anything that *doesn't* need to be jQuery-accessible (text, headers, whatever), to be a part of the template literal